# How to compute effect sizes of single predictor in a logistical regression?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, meta-analysis, effect-size

I have a logistic regression, with a binary response, a continuous predictor, and a categorical one. Is there any way to calculate the effect size of each of those predictors, similar to partial eta-squared in linear models?

Here's an simulated example (in R):

```r
continuous  = rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
categorical = sample(c("A","B"), 1000, replace=TRUE)
response    = continuous + rnorm(1000, 0, 0.1) - 
    ifelse(categorical=="A", -0.3, 0.3) > 0
 
library(car)
model = glm(response ~ continuous + categorical, family=binomial)
```

How would I get the effect size of continuous and categorical, individually?

I saw that we can calculate odds ratio from the coefficients of a logistic equation, but I am not sure if they would be independent of each other as the partial eta squared.